# How to extract key from list of dictionaries

Tags: python

Myd is below

```
t = [{'AB': 'N/A'}, {'BC': 'N/A'}, {'CD': 'N/A'}, {'EF': 'N/A'}]
```

I need to extract all the values from the t

```
def values_extract(t):
   for each in t:
       return [each['AB'],each['BC'],each['CD'],each['EF']]
```

I am getting key error AB

Comment: I'm assuming you want to know why. It's because all but the first dictionaries don't have a key `'AB'`.

Comment: This is a pretty awkwardly-designed data structure so this smells like an XY problem, but `[next(iter(x.values())) for x in t]` should work? Are the inner dicts always 1 element? `[y for x in t for y in x.values()]` works if you want all the vals. I suggest adding more details about what the specification for this structure is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comment from *ggorlen*. To expand upon it a little, use nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract the values or the keys.

```
t = [{'AB': 'N/A'}, {'BC': 'N/A'}, {'CD': 'N/A'}, {'EF': 'N/A'}]

# extract the values:
t_values = [y for x in t for y in x.values()]
print(t_values)
# ['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']

# extract the keys:
t_keys = [y for x in t for y in x.keys()]
print(t_keys)
# ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'EF']
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution, but you can give a try:

```
t = [{'AB': 'N/A'}, {'BC': 'N/A'}, {'CD': 'N/A'}, {'EF': 'N/A'}]
def extract_key(t):
    return [j for k in t for j in list(map(str,k.values()))]
print(extract_key(t))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all values of each dict, the code can be the following

```py
def values_extract(t):
   results = []
   for each in t:
       results.extend(each.values())
   return results
```